# SQL query to List the staff name of all male staff who have sold more than 10 vehicles

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables:

```
Staff (staffNo(PK), fName, lname, gender, DOB, salary, intTelNo)
```

```
CarPurchase (purchaseNo(PK), registrationNo(FK), customerNo(FK), amount, date, staffNo(FK)).
```

I need an SQL query to list the names of all male staff who have sold more than 10 vehicles.

I tried this:

```
SELECT S.f.Name, S.l.Name
FROM Staff AS S.InnerJoin Car Purchase AS P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
WHERE S.gender= “Male”
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.staffNo) \> 10;
```

But the query gave me this error:

> Oops, the OP forgot to include the error message. Maybe they'll edit the question to fix it.

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: Perhaps it is just a typo CarPurchase vs Car Purchase...

Comment: @Shadow I count at least seven obvious typos. Computers are the ultimate pedantic machines. They'll have to learn to be a LOT more precise in this area if they want to have success in this field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT 
  distinct s.fname, 
  count(cp.purchaseNo) 
FROM 
  staff s 
  JOIN carpurchase cp ON cp.staffNo = s.staffno 
WHERE 
  s.gender = 'Male' 
GROUP BY 
  s.fname 
HAVING 
  count(cp.purchaseno) > 10;
```

I juste assumed that gender does contain 'Male' not 'M' or '1'

Comment: sorry, i forgot the group by ;)

Answer (score 0):

This should serve the purpose:

```
SELECT 
  s.staffNo, s.fName 
FROM 
  Staff s 
  JOIN CarPurchase cp ON cp.staffNo = s.staffNo 
WHERE  s.gender = 'Male' 
GROUP BY s.staffNo, s.fName
HAVING count(purchaseNo) > 10
```

Comment: Although this may be the correct answer, there is no description of what went wrong with the original query.

Comment: @Shadow Apart from minor mistakes, GROUP BY clause is missing.

Answer (score 0):

I count at least seven obvious typos, shown here with asterisk above each spot:

```
          *         *
SELECT S.f.Name, S.l.Name
               *    *        * 
FROM Staff AS S.InnerJoin Car Purchase AS P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
                *
WHERE S.gender= “Male”
                                 *
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.staffNo) \> 10;
```

I usually like to be more forgiving about this kind of thing, but seven? The thing is, computers are the ultimate pedantic machines. You will need to learn to be a LOT more precise about these things if you want to find success as a developer.

So here is the original after we clean it up:

```
SELECT S.fName, S.lName
FROM Staff AS S
Inner Join CarPurchase AS P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
WHERE S.gender= 'Male'
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.staffNo) > 10;
```

This still isn't right, but now at least we're to a place where we can start with meaningful fixes...

---

... the first of which is you want to use a `GROUP BY` to go with the `HAVING` clause. This `GROUP BY` should include any fields used in the `SELECT` clause, and it should be sure to uniquely identify each group (names alone are *NOT* generally good enough for this). So let's add that:

```
SELECT S.fName, S.lName
FROM Staff AS S
Inner Join CarPurchase AS P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
WHERE S.gender= 'Male'
GROUP BY s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.staffNo) > 10;
```

Now we're closer... but the having clause still isn't right. When we group by the staff person, and count the distinct staffNo rows within that group, it's always the same value, and so the HAVING expression reduces to `1 > 10`. Instead, we want to count the purchase rows in each group. Again, it's best to base on this on a unique key, like `purchaseNo`. Do that, and we can also drop the `DISTINCT`. That brings us to this:

```
SELECT S.fName, S.lName
FROM Staff AS S
INNER JOIN CarPurchase AS P ON S.staffNo = P.staffNo
WHERE S.gender= 'Male'
GROUP BY s.staffNo, s.fName, s.lName
HAVING COUNT(purchaseNo) > 10;
```

And now, at least we finally have a working query.